# TFS online 2017 upload files via powershell

Tags: tfs

I have a trial 2017 online TFS and i am trying to find a way to upload files with powershell commands. I have tried installing some relevant modules with wrapped api commands, but none of them has anything similar.

Any suggestions?[here are actually the two commands i am trying to execute through ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWC8S.png)

Comment: Are you using TFS 2017 or are you using VIsual Studio Team Services? There is no such thing as "TFS online 2017"

Comment: @arvitis What's that mean for "upload files" here? Do you mean that you want to check in files to TFS or VSTS repository?

Comment: Sorry guys, the question was not very clear. I have visual studio team services and i want to achieve the following : inside the project i can create folders and check in files. there are two commands, upload files and download as zip. These are the ones i want to execute via powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you have to do this? The actions via web portal are more convenient and friendly.

Whatever you can have a try with the REST API.

**Create a folder**: (Create folder `test0232` under `$/0522TFVCScrum/` in below example)

```
Param(
   [string]$vsoAccount = "YourInstance",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = "test@hotmail.com",
   [string]$token = "PAT or Password here"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

function CreateJsonBody
{
    $value = @"
{"changes":[{"changeType":1,"item":{"path":"$/0522TFVCScrum/test0232","isFolder":true}}],"comment":"Added folder test0232"}
"@
 return $value
}

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "https://$($vsoAccount).visualstudio.com/_apis/tfvc/changesets?api-version=4.1-preview.3"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

Write-host $result
```

**Create a file** with below body: (Just replace the Jsonbody in above script, `0229test.ps1` created in this sample)

```
{"changes":[{"changeType":1,"item":{"path":"$/0522TFVCScrum/0229test.ps1","contentMetadata":{"encoding":65001}},"newContent":{"content":"test0229","contentType":0}}],"comment":"Added file 0229test.ps1"}
```

**Upload file:**

Cannot find a way to upload files directly with the REST API, however you can try to [copy files](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/19/use-powershell-to-copy-files-and-folders-to-a-new-location/) to workspace first, then add the files in source control with [Add command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-command), then check in the files with [Checkin command](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfvc/checkin-command).

**Downlaod as Zip:**

You can track the API with tools, then you can get the URL something like this:

```
https://{your account}.visualstudio.com/b3cbc52a-22f6-4de9-ae78-b2b305365ff8/_api/_versioncontrol/itemContentZipped?repositoryId=&path=%24%2F0522TFVCScrum%2Ftest0228&version=T&__v=5
```

Then you can try downlaod with that url in your script.

Comment: thanks for the script. The thing is i am trying to automate some uploads-downloads. That's why i don;t want to use the web portal. I'll try it and post the results!